# ¿Como conectar mi android a una BD externa con PHP o JSP?

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask, https

tengo una duda estoy usando lo que es Asynctask y todo iba bien esta que compre un ssl y lo puse a mi dominio despues de eso me salia un error que no permitia hacer nada por esta con ssl alguien sabe alguna otra libreria que me pueda servir o como solucionar este problema gracias

Comment: Podrias añadir tu clase, que error te muestra ?

Comment: Esto parece un problema de configuración en algún lugar. ¿Tienes una lista blanca de dominios que de podían contactar a la que te faltaría añadir el https? Hace falta añadir más detalles para saber dónde estaría el problema.

Comment: Si pusiste SSL... ¿cambiaste el inicio de la URL de petición, poniendo `https://` al inicio en lugar de `http:`? Si no vas a transferir datos enormes, como vídeos pesados o streaming, puedes probar con [`Volley`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), la librería de Android. Es mucho más fácil de implementar que `AsyncTask`.

Comment: si lo cambie por https:// y aun asi no se puede pero voy a probar con volley